# This would be entirely appropriate if her not having come had strained their relationship

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-would

While answering a certain question, someone (a native speaker) writes:

> "My sister came over last night. She'd been promising to come for
> weeks, and she finally came."
>
> "My sister came over last night. She's been promising to come for
> weeks, and now she's finally come."
>
> In both cases, her coming did take place in the past. The first
> expresses her coming as a past event. The second refers instead to a
> currently existing state produced by her having come. *This **would
> be** entirely appropriate **if**, for example, her not having come
> **had strained** their relationship, while her having come **has produced** a current state in which the relationship **had been
> mended***. That's not explicitly stated of course, but to my mind some
> continuing change in state as a result of her having come is implied
> in the use of the progressive. That may be what would cause a person
> to say "she's been promising", but I'm speculating. Anyway, it doesn't
> sound awkward or incorrect to me. ([source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/shes-been-promising-to-come-for-weeks.3807243/#post-19445672))

Q) What type of conditional is it? Is it a mixed conditional? Does the condition clause refer to a counterfactual situation?

Comment: The difference can be seen if we focus on ***last night***. Both tenses work fine with that time-frame, but if we switch it to ***last summer***, your second (Present Perfect) version would be far less likely (because you could *only* really use it if the speaker's sister had "come over" from some other country, ***and stayed with the speaker ever since***). Does that clear things up?

Comment: Sorry for confusing it. I've edited my question. @FumbleFingers, the entire thing in the blockquote is what the native speaker said, including the sentences in quotation which he gave as examples. He used a conditional sentence in answering the question. But it's not clear to me what he said in that sentence.

Comment: That's a very long-winded "explanation". I take it the reason for it being given at all was that you (or someone else) didn't understand the difference between the two quoted examples. But rather than try to figure out exactly what *his* words "meant" (a bit pointless, if they didn't work for you! :) all you need to focus on is the *actual* difference between the two examples. And that actual difference is simply that Present Perfect implies greater relevance to time of utterance, which I think should be easier to see if you consider the implications of changing ***night*** to ***summer***.

Comment: I have edited in the source of the original post. Good thing we got a little script thingy in place that detects this kind of stuff. Please include your source in the future.